# In PyTest how to config CaptureManager plugin error 'CaptureManager' object has no attribute 'suspendcapture'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following function called from a pytest.

```
def ask_user_input(msg=''):
    """ Asks user to check something manually and answer a question """
    notification = "\n\n???\tANSWER NEEDED\t???\n\n{}".format(msg)

    # suspend input capture by py.test so user input can be recorded here
    capture_manager = pytest.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')
    capture_manager.suspendcapture(in_=True)

    answer = input(notification)

    # resume capture after question have been asked
    capture_manager.resumecapture()

    logging.debug("Answer: {}".format(answer))
    return answer
```

However, I get the following error:
**Error: AttributeError: 'CaptureManager' object has no attribute 'suspendcapture'**

I'm using Python 3.6+. How can I use CaptureManager as pytest.config in the above example seems to no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'CaptureManager' object has no attribute 'suspendcapture'

That's true. The methods are now called ["global"](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/eaa882f3d5340956beb176aa1753e07e3f3f2190/src/_pytest/capture.py#L99): `start_global_capturing`, `stop_global_capturing`, `resume_global_capture`, `suspend_global_capture`, ``.